# Anchoring - Make two components take up half of panel each

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, .net-4.0, anchor

**What I have:**

I have a panel (the white space), and two DataGridViews represented by the green and blue squares.  The panel is anchored to take up most of the center of my screen, and grows/shrinks with the window size.

**What I need:**

I would like the green square to always stay with it's right border in the middle of the screen and take up the left half of the screen.  Equally, I'd like the blue square to stay with its left border in the middle and to take up the right half of the screen.

**Basically, I just want it to always look like this image regardless.**

Do I need to do this programmaticly?  I can't seem to find a combination of anchoring or docking that makes this happen, and adding more panels as containers yields the same issue in the end.

[image: DataGridViews In Panel Layout]

Comment: Nope, the green and blue squares overlap if you do that because they'll stretch much, much bigger but will remain the same pixel width from the left/right.  Thanks though :)

Comment: Worked perfect once I got time to try it :) thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want:

1. Creating a SplitContainer on the screen.

   ```
   Anchor = Top, Bottom, Left, Right
   IsSplitterFixed = True (Trick)
   ```
2. Creating another two datagridviews, each a side inside the SplitterContainer

   ```
   Dock = Fill
   ```

Comment: I didn't even think to look for a container specifically for that situation. :p Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

I generally use a [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) to accomplish this. It is very easy to use (a simple introduction can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2006/04/05/winforms-autolayout-basics-tablelayoutpanel.aspx)).

You create to cells in the first row and set it to 50% width each. In each cell you put one `DataGrid` and you set their `Dock`'ing to `Fill`.

Comment: I prefer this solution.  It feels less heavy-handed than using SplitContainer and easier to configure to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution with the TableLayoutPanel, which works ok.

But layouting inside the TableLayoutPanel is a bit unhandy and restricted if you want to use different positioning.

I found another solution which does it with a little of programming effort:

- For the left item define anchoring to left
- For the right item define no left/right anchoring

This leads into the left item remaining at its location when resizing the form and the right to move staying about the  middle location.

The I added an OnSizeChanged handler to the form, which implements these lines:

```
int widthForItem = Item2.Left - Item1.Left; // you can subtract a distance here
Item1.Width = widthForEachItem;
Item2.Width = widthForEachItem
```